# Correct way to handle errors / unexpected values

Tags: python

I am currently using `assert` in my Python program to stop the program if an incorrect value is received to stop the rest of the code from running.

Is this the best way, or would an `if value == x` then `break` be better, or is there a better way to do this and provide feedback to the user at the same time?

This is how I am currently making sure only a value of 4 is received and the program does not carry on running.

```
assert relayDecoded['relayCmd'] == 4 # Otherwise the relay_connect have not been received (Usually down to a time out)
```

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't use `assert` for controlling the flow of logic in the program, because the user can disable asserts entirely with the `-O` command line flag. What to replace it with depends on the rest of your code, really. `break` might be appropriate, or raising an `Exception` might be better, or you might even `sys.exit`.

Comment: `if condition(x): raise ADescriptiveError("You entered the wrong value, fool!")`. `assert` statements are used for debugging and can be ignored by running python with the `-O` flag.

Comment: Ok thanks, i didn't realise a user could disable them, i need to prevent the rest of the code running and there would be no point contiuning,but at the same time provide feedback to the user about why  the code will not continue, so would an excpetion be the best in this scenario

Comment: Thanks Joel ill try that now

Comment: Some users are intimidated by the long stack trace displayed when the program ends due to an exception. `sys.exit` may look friendlier to non-tech-savvy users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're expecting a `4` in a function, then I would raise a `ValueError` exception, or `TypeError` if a non-int value is received.

If you're expecting the user to enter a `4` then I would print an error message and `break` the execution or use `sys.exit()`.